# Linear system - I do something wrong, I don't know what

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

$$
A := \begin{pmatrix}
5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -4 & 0 \\
0 & 2a & 0 & -2  
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Find $\mathcal{L}=(A,0), a \in \mathbb{R}$

I thought all I had to do is to pring it in step form. So I did this:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & a & 0 & -1  
\end{pmatrix} \\ 
I:5 \\
II:2 \\
III:-4\\
IV:2
$$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -a & -1-\frac{a}{2}  
\end{pmatrix}\\
IV-aII
$$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1-\frac{a}{2}  
\end{pmatrix}\\
IV+aIII
$$

$$
x_4 \cdot (-1-\frac{a}{2}) = 0\\
x_4 = 0 \\
x_3 = 0 \\
x_2 + 1 * 0 + \frac{1}{2} * 0 = 0 \\
x_2 = 0 \\
x_1 = 0
$$

$\Rightarrow \mathcal{L}=\{\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}\}$

I don't believe this is true. But I thought I have only done legal changes.
Can someone explain what I did wrong? I surely did something that wasn't allowed.

Comment: Can you detail your notations ? What is $\mathcal L$ ? What are roman numbers (rows, columns) ?

Comment: What does $(A,0)$ mean? Is it the kernel of the matrix?

Comment: If that is the case, I see that you can deduce $x_1=0=x_3$. But depending on the value of $a$, $x_4$ may not be zero. Namely, if $-1-\frac{a}{2}=0$, then $x_4$ can be anything.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the notations were universal. $L(A,0)$ means that the linear system homogenious, so if we write the matrix as linear system it will end with "= 0" on the right side.
Roman numbers are rows.

And I believe you're right about $-a-\frac{a}{2}$, but why? Can't is just divide by it and remove if from the equation like I did?

Comment: Okay, some more googling later, I realised I didn't explain $\mathcal{L}$ right. Seems that there is no standardised symbol in English for solution set, but in German $\mathcal{L}$ is used. Correct me if I am wrong. $\mathcal{L}=(A,0)$ still denotes that A is to be understood with as a linear system that equals a zero vector.

Comment: If $a=-1$ the kernel is $1$-dimensional; it's spanned by $(0,1,0,-2)^t$ in this case.